# Continue after |truncatechar or break model.TextField() into multiple parts?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

Is there a way to chop text into different bits using django?

I have a model field that is a TextField(), and I want to output it into a nicely formatted way, based on certain lengths, and if there have been images uploaded an so forth.

Is there a way to take this text:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore 
et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut 
aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse 
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa 
qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
```

and chop it into multiple pieces?

I want to be able to do something like this:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do 
<image>
eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud 
exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea 
<chart>
commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu 
fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat 
<link>
non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
```